# Delete a workspace (geoserver) using curl and C#

Tags: c#, geoserver

I searched and didn't found how can I delete a workspace using curl and C#,

I can create a workspace with Curl and C# but I don´t know if I can delete the workspace using the same tools

Thanks in advance

```
       string url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
      request.Method = "DELETE";


        string authInfo = "xxxx:xxxxxxx";

        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<workspace><name>testWorkspace</name></workspace>");
        Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqstr.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Show us some code! What works? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create a workspace programatically, you should be able to delete one (assuming proper credentials).

Take a look at the docs for geoerver's [REST API](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoserver/restconfig/rest-config-api.html). Scroll down a bit to the Workspaces section and you'll notice that you need to send a DELETE method to the server for the workspace you want to delete.

Since you have your create working, you should have all the code you need in order to get the DELETE working.

**EDIT**

After taking a look at the code, I would change the request to use the URL

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testWorkspace
```

and see if you still get a 405 when executing the delete.

Comment: Thanks Gabe and Brian I´m using  request.Method = "DELETE"; but in the WebResponse I get this message "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Comment: According to the documentation that I linked, you'll get 405 if you don't specify the workspace to delete in your post.

Comment: What is the url you are sending the HTTP request to? It should be something like /workspaces/<ws> where <ws> is the workspace you want to delete.